# ¿"esperar al tren" o "esperar el tren"?

Tags: verbos, preposiciones

Hago esta pregunta porque encontré la oración de la imagen de abajo en https://www.esdict.cn/ y creo que es incorrecta, pero me gustaría que alguien me lo confirme.

[image]

Captura de pantalla de [https://www.esdict.cn/liju/es/在下](https://www.esdict.cn/liju/es/%E5%9C%A8%E4%B8%8B)

Para mí, la oración correcta debería ser "La señora Cow espera **al** tren en la siguiente estación". En general, siempre que usamos "esperar" debemos añadir "a". Estos son algunos ejemplos que yo he escrito:

- Estoy esperando **a** mi hermano
- Estoy esperando **al** bus
- Si estás esperando **a** que él lo terminé por su cuenta, entonces tendrás que esperar mucho tiempo.

Agradecería que las respuestas puedan incluir referencias a fuentes relevantes (ejm. Real Academia Española).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando el complemento directo corresponde a una cosa (ej. "tren"), en general no se usa "a". Se debe decir "esperar el tren".

En el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/a) podemos leer:

> 1.3. [La preposición "a"] No se usa:
>
> a) Ante nombres comunes que designan objetos inanimados: Puso el libro
> en la mesa; Regaló un automóvil a su padre.